# How to write a Regexp that allows a single space between words?

Tags: regex, string, utf-8

It's a regexp for the user full name, so I want to allow spaces.
Also, I am using the following regexp to allow only UTF-8 characaters:

```
/^(\p{L}+)$/u
```

Then I saw a post here that said I need to add blank space to the character class, but that didn't work:

```
/^(\p{L} +)$/u
```

Comment: `/^(\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*)$/u`

Comment: [`[` character class `]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: By UTF-8 characters, do you mean all unicode characters? *Every* unicode character is representable in UTF-8

Comment: It depends on your requirements, @sln gave a sample or if you want to allow letters plus space and require the string to start and end with a letter eg something like [`^\b[\pL ]+\b$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZfrMwp/1)

Comment: Thanks, and bobble bubble, what's the difference between yours and sln's solution?

Comment: @TTnote his solution allows one space between words, mine multiple.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I don't want more than one space between words. Btw, it seems to work! Thanks guys, why is this not posted as a regular answer so I can select it :)! Btw, can you explain the regexp so I will learn something new?

Comment: I have already explained it in my answer. For the (utf-8) characters, it means all unicode characters including other spaces. However, I have also explained other limitations, as it does not support all full names around the world.

Comment: @TTnote @sln will probably post his answer, further it looks like you could drop the outer capturing group so it becomes [`/^\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/ZfrMwp/2)

Comment: Thank you, what type of names `/^(\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*)$/u` won't support, for example?
Also, I will try to drop the outer capturing group, thank you!

Comment: Funnily I've totally overread your headline, that you only want to allow a single space in between words (:

Answer (score 4):

According to your regex that accepts full names and in unicode (u) mode, try considering this regex (Compatible for standard POSIX regexes, including Python, JS, and PHP regexes):

- `/^[\p{L}'\-\.]+( [\p{L}'\-\.]+)*$/u`

**This regex would therefore be analyzed by:**

- Any letter characters (including apostrophes, hyphens, and periods): `[\p{L}'\-\.]+`
- And each additional name contains:

  - Exactly one space:
  - Followed by applicable letter characters: `[\p{L}'\-\.]+`
  - All grouped together, forming `( [\p{L}'\-\.]+)*`

This regex supports single and multi-word names (aka a user's full name). If you want to include more characters, modify `[\p{L}'\-\.]` by adding more characters (especially when accented characters are needed such as `ñ`. Currently, it includes letter characters in different scripts as well as the apostrophe and hyphen.

It accepts such names in the PHP or JS engine, you can test it for other engines showing that some engines require you to manually add these characters or change it to `\w` (Test can be verified [here](https://regex101.com/r/VAKaId/5/)):

- `Johnny Appleseed`
- `Martin Harding-Rolls`
- `Daniel O'Brian`
- `IJsbrand van 't IJsselstein`
- `Euclid`
- `Jalapeño Arriba` (You may need to add ñ to the list)
- `S.L.IJ.M.B.A.L P.U.I.S.T`
- `Paul Erdős` (You may need to add Hungarian accented letters to the list)
- `на русском`
- 李富 (Chinese/CJK characters constitute a very large section in Unicode)

It currently does not accept these names:

- `Spaceman Superman` (Space in front of name)
- `OMG`  (Space after name)
- `Johnny  Appleseed` (Two spaces)
- `-- '+` (Unacceptable characters)
- `Mulliganaceous2 Shogun` (Numbers, `\p{L}` only)
- `Pokemon Porygon2` (Numbers, `\p{L}` only)

**Regarding compatibility and the `\w` escape (Edit: the asker specifically wants to exclude names with digits)**

In case `\p{L}` doesn't work, you can try `/^[\w'\-\.]+( [\w'\-\.]+)*$/u`.

- `\w` matches all the ASCII word characters *including* digits and underscore: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- There is *inconsistency* between whether accented characters and characters from other scripts are included.

  - Some regex engines include CJK characters whereas others only include ASCII word characters.
  - If the special characters are excluded, you may have to manually include them.
  - You can also include a range of Unicode characters:

    - To include Chinese characters, use `[\u4E00-\u9FFF]`
  - Intersection can also be used on some engines: `[\w'\-\.&&[\D]]` means the character class of all words, apostrophes, hyphens, and periods, but not digits.

Comment: @TTnote It is not entirely clear what you meant by unicode names. As of now, if you want more unicode characters, you need to manually include them by adding more characters in the square brackets. Also, if you include all of them, you may risk including undesirable characters.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Btw, your regex matches numbers for names as well, it needs to be removed.  You're right, I might get undesirable characters. Then I have to rethink the regex I want. What would you recommendation be? What regex would be the best for names? Which characters should I include and which not?

Comment: There are several approaches though they might not be compatible: You can use character class intersection to exclude digits: `[\w'\-\.]` becomes `[\w'\-\.&&[\D]]` (only works in Java, Ruby), or replace `\w` with `\p{L}` so numeric digits are excluded (unicode regex flag only). Again, watch out for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach that allows a single space in between letters only (pcre/php pattern).

```
/^(?>\pL+ ?\b)+$/u
```

- `\pL+` matches one or more unicode letters
- `?` the single space is [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)
- the word boundary `\b` requires the [quantified](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) to end with a letter.
- more compatible to other regex flavors like Ruby or .NET: `^(?:\p{L}+ ?\b)+$`

[See demo at regex101 for testing](https://regex101.com/r/ZfrMwp/6).

(this pattern requires the string to start with a letter and end with a letter)

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution only works for the PHP case. His answer does not specify which regex it uses. In my answer, I have added notes about compatibility between different regex engines.

Comment: @Oighea Thank you for the comment, yes I thought it's about PHP/PCRE. However it should also work in Java and I provided a version for .NET, Ruby.

Comment: Here is the other question: Since `\w` have different degree of inclusiveness, some engines may include only ASCII word characters where others accept a much broader range. Is there a more compact way to express any word character including accented characters and chinese characters in case the `\w` doesn't include them? Java `\w` only includes ASCII word characters.

Comment: @Oighea I assume in pcre if used together with unicode `u` flag, `\w` would be equivalent to `[\pL\pN_]`. Regarding the other regex flavors there are many questions/answers about this topic.

Comment: Ultimately, some differences may be needed when using the regex for different languages but the overall way or organizing this regex is the same. Most importantly, it is just how the extra characters are included or excluded

Comment: Thanks guys! Then instead of entire unicode characters, what would your recommendations be? Which ones should I leave? Btw, the regex above won't match certain languages

Answer (score 0):

This regex in my opinion works bet for full user name,

```
/^([a-zA-Z' ]+)$/
```

I don't think you should put regex on a name at all because matching all the names all over the world with the foreign characters and different languages is quite an over complicated job with not a lot of advantage.

Trying to include foreign characters

```
/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.']+$/u
```

Comment: But, it matches stuff like `,,,,,,,,,,` and `------------`

Comment: And I need unicode letters such as French, Portuguese, Hebrew, Arabic

Comment: Your current regex allows multiple spaces between letters, such as `ABC   AAA`

Comment: That's what the OP wants to achieve I believe? @Oighea

Comment: Yep. The keyword is *single space*. I have corrected my regex, and also noted that in some regex engines the accented letters are already included.